# s3distcp not working for me on CDH4.5

Tags: hadoop

I'm running CDH4.5.  I was trying to use distcp to s3n but am getting issues since I upgraded to 4.5.
I'm trying to get s3distcp up and running, but am getting issues.  I downloaded it, and am running this command:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/s3distcp.jar  --src hdfs://NN:8020/path/to/destination/folder --dest s3n://acceseKeyId:secretaccesskey@mybucket/destination/
```

but I'm getting error of:

```
INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201312042223_10889_r_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.amazon.external.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.CopyFilesReducer.executeDownloads(CopyFilesReducer.java:209)
    at com.amazon.external.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.CopyFilesReducer.reduce(CopyFilesReducer.java:196)
    at com.amazon.external.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.CopyFilesReducer.reduce(CopyFilesReducer.java:30)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:506)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax

INFO mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: NA
13/12/12 13:55:25 INFO s3distcp.S3DistCp: Try to recursively delete hdfs:/tmp/985ffdb0-1bc8-4d00-aba6-fd9b18e905f1/tempspace
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error running job
    at com.amazon.external.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp.run(S3DistCp.java:586)
    at com.amazon.external.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp.run(S3DistCp.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at com.amazon.external.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.Main.main(Main.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1388)
    at com.amazon.external.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp.run(S3DistCp.java:568)
```

I then put access key and id into my core-site.xml on all the data and name node:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
    <value>bippitybopityboo</value>
  </property>   
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId</name>
    <value>supercalifragilisticexpialadoscious</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
    <value>bippitybopityboo</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId</name>
    <value>supercalifragilisticexpialadoscious</value>
  </property>
```

and still was getting same error when i tried this:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/s3distcp.jar  --src hdfs://NN:8020/path/to/destination/folder --dest s3n://mybucket/destination/
```

Is there some configuration I'm supposed to do, or am I missing some jar files or executing it incorrectly?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.  The fix was to change from s3n to s3a.

```
# change from this
--dest s3n://acceseKeyId:secretaccesskey@mybucket/destination/
# to this
--dest s3a://acceseKeyId:secretaccesskey@mybucket/destination/
```

See also here: [S3 Support in Apache Hadoop](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3)

s3 is deprecated s3n is not maintained so use s3a going forward.

S3A is the recommended S3 Client for Hadoop 2.7 and later

> A successor to the S3 Native, s3n:// filesystem, the S3a: system uses
>   Amazon's libraries to interact with S3. This allows S3a to support
>   larger files (no more 5GB limit), higher performance operations and
>   more. The filesystem is intended to be a replacement for/successor to
>   S3 Native: all objects accessible from s3n:// URLs should also be
>   accessible from s3a simply by replacing the URL schema.
>
> Unmainteained: S3N FileSystem (URI scheme: s3n://)
>
> S3N is the S3 Client for Hadoop 2.6 and earlier. From Hadoop 2.7+,
>   switch to s3a
>
> A native filesystem for reading and writing regular files on S3.With
>   this filesystem is that you can access files on S3 that were written
>   with other tools. Conversely, other tools can access files written
>   using Hadoop. The S3N code is stable and widely used, but is not
>   adding any new features (which is why it remains stable).
>
> S3N requires a compatible version of the jets3t JAR on the classpath.
>
> Since Hadoop 2.6, all work on S3 integration has been with S3A. S3N is
>   not maintained except for security risks —this helps guarantee
>   security. Most bug reports against S3N will be closed as WONTFIX and
>   the text "use S3A". Please switch to S3A if you can -and do try it
>   before filing bug reports against S3N.
>
> (Deprecated) S3 Block FileSystem (URI scheme: s3://)

Answer (score -1):

You need the AWS SDK for Java. Grab it from http://aws.amazon.com/de/sdkforjava/ and either put the jar into `/usr/lib/hadoop/lib` or pass it with the `-libjars` option. Assuming version 1.7.1 of the AWS SDK the command would then look like:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/s3distcp.jar \
    -libjars aws-java-sdk-1.7.1/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.7.1.jar \
    --src hdfs://NN:8020/path/to/destination/folder \
    --dest s3n://acceseKeyId:secretaccesskey@mybucket/destination/
```

References:

- AWS SDK for Java: http://aws.amazon.com/de/sdkforjava/
- libjars option: http://grepalex.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-libjars/